# Android app crashes even while not edited, how can I solve it?

Tags: disassembly, anti-debugging, patching, patch-reversing, apk

Installed an application from **google playstore** and then transferred to it my **computer** to apparently edit it and without any changes I made to it then I tried to install it through **ADB**, well the installation was fine but When I tried to start the **application** it just crashes. also tried to clear app data to see any solution but it didn't work! and when I look into the logcat I find the following which is almost informative except this vague error

`04-02 17:15:29.095  3053  3071 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ibsbankmobile, PID: 3053`

**all other logcat is below:**

```
04-02 17:15:12.237  2526  2609 I PackageManager: init_copy idx=0: MeasureParams{56c9329 com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:12.237  2526  2609 I PackageManager: startCopy UserHandle{0}: MeasureParams{56c9329 com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:16.415  2526  2609 I PackageManager: init_copy idx=0: MeasureParams{5d8cfbb com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:16.415  2526  2609 I PackageManager: startCopy UserHandle{0}: MeasureParams{5d8cfbb com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:18.871  2526  2609 I PackageManager: init_copy idx=0: MeasureParams{95d4782 com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:18.874  2526  2609 I PackageManager: startCopy UserHandle{0}: MeasureParams{95d4782 com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:21.988  1865  1865 I AppStorageSettings: Clearing user data for package : com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:21.996  2526 27990 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.ibsbankmobile appid=10298 user=0: clear data
04-02 17:15:22.049  2526  2558 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.ibsbankmobile appid=10298 user=-1: clearApplicationUserData
04-02 17:15:22.096  2526  2609 V ActivityManager: Broadcast: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 (has extras) } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=null
04-02 17:15:22.097  2526  2609 V ActivityManager: Broadcast: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 (has extras) } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=null
04-02 17:15:22.102  1865  1865 I AppStorageSettings: Cleared user data for package : com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:22.124  3032  3032 I GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_ALL packageName=com.ibsbankmobile]
04-02 17:15:22.142  2526  2609 I PackageManager: init_copy idx=0: MeasureParams{901be7d com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:22.143  2526  2609 I PackageManager: startCopy UserHandle{0}: MeasureParams{901be7d com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:22.179  2526  2558 D ProcessManager.AS: *** Launch app com.android.chrome/10041 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 (has extras) } from android/1000
04-02 17:15:22.928  2863  2863 D ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.browserservices.ClientAppBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=org.chromium.chrome.browser.browserservices.ClientAppBroadcastReceiver@ae98dda
04-02 17:15:22.944  2526  2853 D ProcessManager.AS: *** Launch app com.android.documentsui/10009 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 (has extras) } from android/1000
04-02 17:15:23.084  2885  2885 D ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.documentsui/.PackageReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.android.documentsui.PackageReceiver@c1db393
04-02 17:15:23.101  2526  3601 D ProcessManager.AS: *** Launch app com.google.android.apps.photos/10070 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 (has extras) } from android/1000
04-02 17:15:23.832  2902  2902 D ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 cmp=com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.libraries.social.mediastoresync.reset.impl.MediaStoreClearedReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.google.android.libraries.social.mediastoresync.reset.impl.MediaStoreClearedReceiver@ef8af
04-02 17:15:23.858  3032  3032 D ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver@b04b693
04-02 17:15:23.955  3739  3739 D ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED dat=package:com.ibsbankmobile flg=0x10 cmp=com.transsion.phonemanager/com.cyin.himgr.applicationmanager.receiver.AppReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.cyin.himgr.applicationmanager.receiver.AppReceiver@1aa53d7
04-02 17:15:23.968  3739  3739 D HiManager_log: HiManager_HiManager_ServerAppReceiver: setting clean data pkg: com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:23.982  2526 27996 D PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockChanging: flags=1, tag="Icing", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10015, ownerPid=3381, workSource=WorkSource{10015 com.google.android.gms, 10284 com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:23.987  2526  2548 D PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockChanging: flags=1, tag="Icing", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10015, ownerPid=3381, workSource=WorkSource{10284 com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:23.999  3381  2013 I Icing   : doRemovePackageData com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:24.037  2418  2418 V AlarmClock: AlarmBroadcastReceiver recevied pkgName = com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:24.126  2526  3599 D PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockChanging: flags=1, tag="Icing", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10015, ownerPid=3381, workSource=WorkSource{10015 com.google.android.gms, 10284 com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:28.690  2526  3599 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity bnds=[12,234][276,492] (has extras)} from uid 10022 on display 0
04-02 17:15:28.700  2526  3599 V WindowManager: Set focused app to: AppWindowToken{9b32dfb token=Token{8baa9f5 ActivityRecord{2d9b2c u0 com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity t28124}}} old focus=AppWindowToken{fb2d555 token=Token{ccee73f ActivityRecord{6e6b75e u0 com.transsion.hilauncher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher t27849}}} moveFocusNow=true
04-02 17:15:28.700  2526  3599 V WindowManager: findFocusedWindow: Reached focused app=AppWindowToken{9b32dfb token=Token{8baa9f5 ActivityRecord{2d9b2c u0 com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity t28124}}}
04-02 17:15:28.719  2526  2587 D ViewRootImpl[ibsbankmobile]: hardware acceleration is disabled, fakeHwAccelerated = true, HardwareRenderer.sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, HardwareRenderer.sSystemRendererDisabled = false, this = ViewRoot{9143ca9 Starting com.ibsbankmobile,ident = 415}
04-02 17:15:28.731   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:0,p:-1,c:303) setConsumerName: Starting com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:28.731   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:0,p:-1,c:303) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1 height=1
04-02 17:15:28.732  2526  2587 V WindowManager: findFocusedWindow: Reached focused app=AppWindowToken{9b32dfb token=Token{8baa9f5 ActivityRecord{2d9b2c u0 com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity t28124}}}
04-02 17:15:28.737  2526  3510 I ActivityManager: Start proc 3053:com.ibsbankmobile/u0a298 for activity com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity
04-02 17:15:28.745   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:0,p:-1,c:303) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1080 height=1920
04-02 17:15:28.752   303   436 I BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:2,p:2526,c:303) connect(P): api=2 producer=(2526:system_server) producerControlledByApp=false
04-02 17:15:28.753   303  1002 I BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:2,p:2526,c:303) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-02 17:15:28.771  2526  2798 I libPerfService: [perfNotifyAppState] foreground:com.ibsbankmobile, pid:3053
04-02 17:15:28.771  2526  1395 I PPS     : [PPSNotifyAppState] pack:com.ibsbankmobile, com:com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity, state:1,ActiveCount = 1
04-02 17:15:28.771  2526  1395 I PPS     : [PPSNotifyAppState] nPackNum:102, pack:com.ibsbankmobile, com:com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity, state:1, pid:3053, last_boost_tid:3053
04-02 17:15:28.771  2526  2798 I libPerfService: perfCheckPackAffinity foreground:com.ibsbankmobile, latest:
04-02 17:15:28.804  2526  2588 D ProcessManager: recentPackage baseActivity : com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:28.824  3053  3053 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ibsbankmobile-1/lib/arm64
04-02 17:15:28.856  2899  2899 D SystemServicesProxy: getRecentTasks:TASK = id=28124 stackId=1 user=0 lastActiveTime=1585836928771 componentComponentInfo{com.ibsbankmobile/com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity}/isExcluded = false/includeFrontMostExcludedTask = false/isFirstValidTask = true/t.id = 28124
04-02 17:15:29.092  3053  3071 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ibsbankmobile-1/lib/arm64
04-02 17:15:29.095  3053  3071 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ibsbankmobile, PID: 3053
04-02 17:15:29.100  2526  1395 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity
04-02 17:15:29.105  2526  1395 V WindowManager: Set focused app to: AppWindowToken{fb2d555 token=Token{ccee73f ActivityRecord{6e6b75e u0 com.transsion.hilauncher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher t27849}}} old focus=AppWindowToken{9b32dfb token=Token{8baa9f5 ActivityRecord{2d9b2c u0 com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity t28124}}} moveFocusNow=true
04-02 17:15:29.112  2526  3072 D AES     : onEndOfErrorDumpThread: data_app_crash Process: com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.112  2526  3072 D AES     : Package: com.ibsbankmobile v3 (1)
04-02 17:15:29.114  2526  3072 D AES     :     process : com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.114  2526  3072 D AES     :      module : com.ibsbankmobile v3 (1)
04-02 17:15:29.116  2526  3072 D AEE_LIBAEE: shell: raise_exp(4, 3053, -1361051648, com.ibsbankmobile, 0x0x7223e196e0, 0x0x0)
04-02 17:15:29.133  3073  3073 I AEE_AED : [preset_info] pid: 3053, tid: -1361051648, name: UNKNOWN  >>> com.ibsbankmobile <<<
04-02 17:15:29.133  3073  3073 V AEE_AED : dashboard_record_update() : rec->module = com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.150  3053  3053 D ActivityThread: EYE startEyeVerifyBroadcast packagename=com.ibsbankmobile; ClassName=com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity
04-02 17:15:29.152  2526  3597 V ActivityManager: Broadcast: Intent { act=com.rlk.android.APPLOCK_RECEIVER flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.rlk.eyeverify.activity (has extras) } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=ProcessRecord{9cb3bc0 3053:com.ibsbankmobile/u0a298}
04-02 17:15:29.157 18792 18792 D LOGTAG_AppLockRecieve: start activity PackageName=com.ibsbankmobile    ClassName=com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity
04-02 17:15:29.172 18792 18792 D LOGTAG_VerifyInterceptor: start Eye check activity PackageName=com.ibsbankmobile       ;  ClassName=com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity;  IsLocked=false
04-02 17:15:29.187  3053  3053 D OpenGLRenderer: <com.ibsbankmobile> is running.
04-02 17:15:29.189  2526  2559 D ViewRootImpl[ibsbankmobile]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{65d6111 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile,ident = 416}
04-02 17:15:29.214  2526  2559 V WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow:2347 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:187 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:753 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:355
04-02 17:15:29.215  2526  2559 D WindowManager: Input focus has changed to Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:29.216  2526  2587 I WindowManager: Focus moving from null to Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:29.216  2526  2587 I WindowManager: Gaining focus: Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile}
04-02 17:15:29.225   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:0,p:-1,c:303) setConsumerName: Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.225   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:0,p:-1,c:303) setDefaultBufferSize: width=193 height=193
04-02 17:15:29.237  3053  3053 D ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{6a638df com.ibsbankmobile/com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity,ident = 0}
04-02 17:15:29.238   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:0,p:-1,c:303) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1272 height=641
04-02 17:15:29.242  2526 22035 D OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7227d10000 initialize window=0x7235518600, title=Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.252   303   436 I BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:2526,c:303) connect(P): api=1 producer=(2526:system_server) producerControlledByApp=false
04-02 17:15:29.254  3053  3053 V PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{6a638df com.ibsbankmobile/com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@fe5f5ef[MainActivity],statusBarBackground visible =true,statusColor: 0xff757575->
04-02 17:15:29.266   303  1763 I BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:2526,c:303) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-02 17:15:29.277  2526  3601 I PPS     : [PPSNotifyAppState] pack:com.ibsbankmobile, com:com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity, state:0,ActiveCount = 0
04-02 17:15:29.277  2526  3601 I PPS     : [PPSNotifyAppState] nPackNum:102, pack:com.ibsbankmobile, com:com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity, state:0, pid:3053, last_boost_tid:3053
04-02 17:15:29.278  3073  3073 D AEE_AED :   Process:com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.278  3073  3073 I AEE_AED : com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.279  3073  3073 D AEE_AED :   Module:com.ibsbankmobile v3 (1)
04-02 17:15:29.279  3073  3073 I AEE_AED : com.ibsbankmobile v3 (1)
04-02 17:15:29.279  3073  3073 D AEE_AED :   Backtrace:Process: com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.279  3073  3073 D AEE_AED : Package: com.ibsbankmobile v3 (1)
04-02 17:15:29.282  3073  3073 I AEE_AED : Process: com.ibsbankmobile
04-02 17:15:29.282  3073  3073 I AEE_AED : Package: com.ibsbankmobile v3 (1)
04-02 17:15:29.287   303   432 I BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:2526,c:303) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-02 17:15:29.288  2526  3601 I WindowManager: Failed to capture screenshot of Token{8baa9f5 ActivityRecord{2d9b2c u0 com.ibsbankmobile/.MainActivity t28124 f}} appWin=Window{e98a1cf u0 Starting com.ibsbankmobile} drawState=4
04-02 17:15:29.311   303  1763 I BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:2526,c:303) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-02 17:15:29.433  2899  2899 D SystemServicesProxy: getRecentTasks:TASK = id=28124 stackId=1 user=0 lastActiveTime=1585836929105 componentComponentInfo{com.ibsbankmobile/com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity}/isExcluded = false/includeFrontMostExcludedTask = false/isFirstValidTask = true/t.id = -1
04-02 17:15:29.609   303  1763 I BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:2,p:-1,c:303) disconnect(P): api -1
04-02 17:15:29.612   303  1763 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:2,p:-1,c:303) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
04-02 17:15:29.613  2526  2587 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.ibsbankmobile) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2137 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:949 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1470 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2708 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:376 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:587 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:435 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateAppWindowsLocked:184
04-02 17:15:29.626   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:2,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(C)
04-02 17:15:29.645   303  1002 I BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:2,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(P): api 2
04-02 17:15:29.665  2526  3514 I PPS     : [PPSNotifyAppState] pack:com.ibsbankmobile, com:com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity, state:2,ActiveCount = 1
04-02 17:15:29.665  2526  3514 I PPS     : [PPSNotifyAppState] nPackNum:102, pack:com.ibsbankmobile, com:com.ibsbankmobile.MainActivity, state:2, pid:3053, last_boost_tid:16629
04-02 17:15:29.667   303  1763 I BufferQueue: [Starting com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f1bf5000,id:6203,api:2,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
04-02 17:15:34.750  2526  2588 I ActivityManager: Killing 3053:com.ibsbankmobile/u0a298 (adj 900): doclean
04-02 17:15:34.751  2526  2588 D ActivityManager: handleAppDiedLocked: app = ProcessRecord{9cb3bc0 3053:com.ibsbankmobile/u0a298}, app.pid = 3053
04-02 17:15:34.758  2526  1395 W ActivityManager: Ignoring remove of inactive process: ProcessRecord{9cb3bc0 0:com.ibsbankmobile/u0a298}
04-02 17:15:34.784   303   436 I BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:-1,c:303) disconnect(P): api 1
04-02 17:15:34.784   303   436 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:-1,c:303) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
04-02 17:15:34.788   303  1763 I BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:-1,c:303) disconnect(P): api 1
04-02 17:15:34.794  2526  2559 V WindowManager: Remove Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile} client=d7bb276, surfaceController=Surface(name=Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile) Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2522 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2517 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:206 android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow:3700
04-02 17:15:34.796  2526  2559 V WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile EXITING} to Window{78def60 u0 com.transsion.hilauncher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.setupWindowForRemoveOnExit:2503 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2647 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2522 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2517
04-02 17:15:34.807  2526  2587 I WindowManager: Focus moving from Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile EXITING} to Window{78def60 u0 com.transsion.hilauncher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}
04-02 17:15:34.808  2526  2587 I WindowManager: Losing focus: Window{b4f2077 u0 Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile EXITING}
04-02 17:15:34.847  2526  2587 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2137 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:949 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2114 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:435 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:236 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:184 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8481 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:110
04-02 17:15:34.857   303   303 I BufferQueueConsumer: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(C)
04-02 17:15:34.857   303   303 I BufferQueue: [Application Error: com.ibsbankmobile](this:0x75f5216000,id:6204,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
```

the app in question can be found [here](https://apkcombo.com/en-so/ibs-mobile-banking/com.ibsbankmobile)

can anyone tell or explain to me what is going wrong here? and how can I circumvent it?

***any help would be appreciated***

Comment: Does the app crash when installed normally? If not, then you changed something important during the transfer process even if you did not patch the binary.

Answer (score 2):

```
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ibsbankmobile-1/lib/arm64

E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ibsbankmobile, PID: 3053
```

The warning here shows that you have a missing path: `/data/app/.../lib/arm64`

This directory contains binary (compiled) libraries that belong to the app. If you repack an app, whether you changed its code or not, you have to make sure that you pack, and sign, these files.

Comment: thank you for the clarification but How can I pack, and sign, these files plz?

Comment: This is not a straightforward process and it takes some time. Repack: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/ Sign: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signing-manually

Comment: @Yomtamz , Specifically how can I sign binary (compiled) libraries  of the app, should I use **Jarsigner**?

Comment: You don't have to sign individual files, you just have to make sure that they are included in the new JAR (or APK) when you sign it with "jarsigner".

Comment: sorry for my noobness, it is true the lib  folder is not there on the app but can you tell me how can I put it there or should I pull from the android device?

Comment: on the app download page, I saw this file **libs-appname_1.apk** how this file could help? it is another apk does it need to be decompiled? how can I integrate to the app when rebuilding? do i create a lib folder?

Comment: How did you first unpacked the APK? Did you use a tools, like apktool, or did you just unzip it like a regular JAR file? If the original APK did not work either, then this file probably has what you need in it. If this is the case, unpack both files with apk tool, put the directories in their place and pack again with the tool... then sign it